# Stuck on an integral of form $\int\exp(-\frac{\alpha}{m^2} - \beta m)\frac{dm}{m}$. Any ideas?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

My statistical model involves the multiplication of a scalar random variable $X|X \geq 0 \sim 2\mathcal{N}(x;0,\sigma^2)\ \mathbb{I} \ [x \in \mathcal{R}_+]$, or a gaussian variable that must be strictly above zero, and and scalar exponentially distributed magnitude $M \sim \exp(m;\lambda)$.

I would like to find the distribution of $C =M\cdot X$ which is clearly still positive.

So far I have that:

$f_C(c) = \int_0^{\infty}f_{X|M}(\frac{c}{M}|M = m)f_M(m)\frac{dm}{m}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \int_0^{\infty}f_{X}(\frac{c}{m})f_M(m)\frac{dm}{m}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \sqrt{\frac{2}\pi} \frac{\lambda}{\sigma}\int_0^{\infty}\exp \left({-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{c}{\sigma m}\right)^2} \right) \cdot \exp \left(- \lambda m\right) \frac{dm}{m}$

I haven't really founding a promising direction to pursue to integrate this. Part of what makes it difficult is the integration of the form $\int\exp(-\frac{\alpha}{m^2} - \beta m)\frac{dm}{m}$ and everything I try seems fruitless. I've considered modifying the $M$ distribution, but the exponential seems reasonable for my application. It's modelling something physical (diffusion of a single particle), but the magnitude $M$ is not determined by some well-defined rigourous process so it's quite possible the $M$ distribution has nothing to do with physics inherently. But I thought I could change the magnitude to the form $\sim \frac{1}{Z}e^{(k_bT)^{-1}U(m)}$ or even $\sim \frac{1}{Z}e^{-(k_bT)^{-1}U(m,x)} $ for some $U(\cdots)$'s if necessary, but I'm not sure if either of those would be physically justifiable. Any ideas?

EDIT: for clarity.

Comment: "...a gaussian variable that must be strictly above zero..." isn't it [a truncated normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)?

Comment: Hmmm, it appears so. All the same, it doesn't appear to make this particular integration any easier.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way to express this is in terms of the [Meijer G-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function).

Comment: @Lucian Wow. That is really horrible. That looks terrible. Buuut...., it doesn't actually appear to be all that much of a dead end. From [here](http://www.ams.org/notices/201307/rnoti-p866.pdf) "The family G of G–functions has remarkable
closure properties: it is closed under the reflections
$x \rightarrow −x$ and $x \rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$, multiplication by powers,
differentiation, integration, the Laplace transform,
the Euler transform, and the multiplicative convolution" It might be worth using for my application.